# What kind of visa needed for 2-3 days stay in Singapore?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, singapore

I am Indian passport holder but currently in Tokyo on work visa for a year.

So, Next year I am planning to go to India for 15 days but while going to India from Japan I would like to go to Singapore or Thailand or Somewhere in China for 2-3 days. and then go back to India.

Tokyo⟶Singapore(2-3 days)⟶Delhi

this is my travel plan. so what kind of visa I will need in Singapore ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news! As the Indian citizen holder of a long-term Japanese visa, **you're eligible for the 96-Hour Visa Free Transit** scheme in Singapore, which gives you up to 4 days in Singapore without needing to apply for a visa.

Details here: https://www.ica.gov.sg/enteranddeparting/before/enteranddeparting_before_vftf

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you have any Idea about China/Thailand/Philippines ?

Comment: @HungryExplorer Please ask those as separate questions.